# ReactJS Array fill with key in JSX element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I'm looking for the shortest approach to generate multiple JSX element.
For example, if I need to generate 10 `<span>` I can easily use Array map function

```
{[...Array(10)].map((x, i) =>
    <span key={i} ></span>
)}
```

There's nothing wrong with the above approach but I want another shorter version like,

```
Array(10).fill(<span></span>);
```

However, React will shout about not having the unique 'key' props. does anyone have a clean solution without using the random()?

Answer (score 14):

The `Array(10).fill(<span></span>);` solution has more problems than just the key: It uses the **same** span for each entry in the array, which is presumably not what you want.

You can use [`Array#from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
Array.from({length:10}, (_, i) => <span key={i}></span>);
// or
Array.from(Array(10), (_, i) => <span key={i}></span>);
```

It still uses a callback, but you're going to need that no matter what. It's slightly less verbose, and more efficient (not that it matters in 99.999% of cases), than the spread-and-map.

Comment: i don't see much diff between suggested answer and `[...Array(10)].map((x, i) =>
    <span key={i} ></span>
)` :P, because op was trying to skip the loop

Comment: @MayankShukla: Right, there isn't. The main point here is that the apparent simplicity of `Array#fill` is illusory, one will need a callback.

Comment: @mayank one iteration instead of two?

Comment: Thanks, Ideally I would like to avoid `key` here if possible as it's just for CSS animation purpose. but wondering if there's any shorter version for this dumb job.

Comment: @JonasW., i think yes :)

Comment: @Hasanavi: I don't think so. You can give yourself a utility function, of course... I've often thought of proposing something to TC39 (the committee for moving JavaScript forward) for building an array of length N from a repeated series of callbacks. But responsibly putting forward a proposal carries a significant time commitment I can't currently justify.

Comment: @t.j. but hanging around on SO? :)

Comment: @JonasW.: I can't justify that, either. :-)